# Object creation/initialization semantics in Java

Tags: java, object

I'm a die-hard C++ fan who is picking up Java for Android apps.  In C++, the canonical way of creating and initializing an object would be to totally intialize it in the constructor:

```
class Message {
  string payload;
  int client;
  // etc.

public:
  Message(string payload, int client)
    : payload(payload)
    , client(client)
  {}
};
```

This seems possible to do in Java.  It gets a bit uglier because I want to make certain members `const` (the best Java can do is `final`), but generally I can figure it out.

But now I'm running across libraries such as `FreeHEP-XDR`, whose `XDRSerializable` interface specifies a signature:

```
void read(XDRDataInput in);
```

This function, which will be implemented by `Message`, is obviously not a static instantiator, as it returns `void`.  The `Message` object would have to be fully constructed, probably with a default constructor, before calling this function.  This bothers me:  the caller can easily pass an `XDRDataInput` in the constructor, and anyway I'll be initializing the object twice (once in the default constructor, again in `read`).  Most egregiously, implementing this requires me to drop my `final` modifier from certain `Message` data members, because they'll be modified after the constructor is finished!

Is this par for the course for Java?  What's the object protection, creation, and initialization paradigm?

Comment: XDRDataInput is a pointer.

Comment: Sure, but the object I'm calling it on would have to be initialized before the call.  The members' initial values will then be clobbered by `read`.

Comment: I'm not concerned about creating another `XDRDataInput`.  The function I'm implementing would be `Message.read(XDRDataInput in)`.  The `Message` must be initialized before calling `read`.

Comment: @Thilo Right, I'm misinterpreting this. My apologies.

Comment: i really dont understand what's the problem. u create an object (pointer to memory) and then pass it to read to fill variables...

Comment: Nope, `read` is a *member function* of a class I would implement.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty u mean read is a member of XDRDataInput?

Comment: No, `read` is a member of `thirtythreeforty.Message` which *implements* the interface `XDRSerializable`.

Comment: is this a complaint that the api is forcing you to make a mutable object when you'd rather it be immutable?

Comment: I wish you had said up front that `Message` implements `XDRSerializable`.  That's a key piece of information that I think was missing, and everybody got confused.

Comment: There, edited; hopefully that's better.  @NathanHughes, yes, mostly.  And the resulting question of "is there a different paradigm I'm not aware of?".

Comment: i think there's just a lot of room for api designers to go wrong. but if you want to use their api you're stuck with following their rules.

Comment: Agree with Nathan here.  I've been staring at this for some time now trying to figure out what the desired result is; and the conclusion I can't get past is that the problem is due to the way the library author designed the library, and the problem would be just the same in C++ if someone had designed a C++ library the same way.  I'm not a C++ expert, so maybe there would be a way around it there that I don't see.

Comment: You would still have the same problem in C++.  I have just seen the same pattern several times and thought there might be a correlation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the main issue with constructors is that they are not polymorphic. Meaning that the client whose invoking such constructors needs to always know what concrete type is she building. By deferring initialization and construction you can, pontentially, take the decision of which concrete instance you want to create at point a and polimorfically initialize it at point b.

Also, java does not have any way to force implementors of a certain contract (an interface, by example) to define a certain constructor. So it is either adding a weak condition to the interface contract (like a comment in the javadoc saying that implementors should provide a constructor that receives XHRDataInput) or adding a initialization method to the interface and forcing you to provide an empty constructor instead (which is by far a more common practice, probably inherited from the JavaBeans "specification").

Having said that I will also state: Yes it totally breaks your "final" semantics. You can add a check in your "read" method that checks over a certain condition and ensure that your object is initialized only once (throwing an Exception if read is invoked twice), but that is totally up to you.

Comment: This explanation makes a lot of sense, thanks.  Although, now I get to have little getters sprinkled in my code where `final public` members would have worked fine.  Eh, Java.

Comment: That is probably one reason why we avoid public fields at all.